# Как уменьшить количество символов

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода, соревнование

Есть скрипт на JavaScript принимаюший n строк и находящий наибольшую общую подстроку.

```
function z(e) {
if (e.length)
for (n = e[0].length, l = n; l; l--)
  for (s = 0; s <= n - l; s++)
    if (r = e[0].substring(s, s + l), e.every(n => ~n.indexOf(r))) return r;
return ''
}
console.log(z(process.argv.slice(2)));
```

Можно ли сделать это за еще меньшее количество символов?

Comment: Есть регламент на количество строк? Можно ли объявлять переменные без `var` или `let`?

Comment: В задаче существует только одно ограничение: Менее 300 символов(200 - хорошо, 120 - превосходно).
Можно использовать другой алгоритм. Это просто максимум, до чего я дошел.

Comment: @degradise, и можете показать пример входных/выходных данных?

Comment: Используйте любой обфускатор. Самый популярный наверно uglifyjs. https://skalman.github.io/UglifyJS-online/

Answer (score 2):

## JS, 119 символов

```
z=a=>{if(r=a[0],!r)return'';for(i=0;i<r.length;i+=1)for(j=1;j<a.length;j+=1)if(r[i]!==a[j][i])r=r.slice(0,i);return r};
```

Answer (score 1):

Зачем Вам меньше символов? Главное, что работало правильно и код был понятен. Я немного поправил Ваш код

```
 function z(e) {
      if (!e.length) return ''
      for (let n = e[0].length, l = n; l; l--)
        for (let s = 0; s <= n - l; s++)
          if (let r = e[0].substring(s, s + l) && e.every(n => ~n.indexOf(r))) return r;
 }
```

Comment: По условию задачи: чем меньше символов - тем лучше. Пока что уперся в это решение и больше ничего придумать не могу.

Comment: @Node_pro, тестировали функцию?

Answer (score 0):

166 "чистых" символов против твоих 180. Меньше не могу. Логику не затронул, просто старался заметить повторяющиеся моменты.`use strict` не пройдет.

```
z = e => {
x = e[0]
if (!x) return ''
n = x.length
for (l = n; l; l--)
  for (s = 0; s <= n - l; s++)
    if (r = x.substring(s, s + l), e.every(n => ~n.indexOf(r))) return r;
}
console.log(z(process.argv.slice(2)));
```